# Smarty and javascript inside of literal

Tags: php, smarty

I want to be able to move the google analytics code into that database.

Originally I would manually do this inside of the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
{literal}
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-19807844-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
{/literal}
--></script>
```

How do I do something like below, that allows the user to enter into the database their own analytics

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
{literal}
{$portal.google_analytics}
{/literal}
--></script>
```

Comment: That will print out a *literal* `{$portal.google_analytics}`. Drop the `literal` tags and try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

{$portal.google_analytics}

--></script>
```

or if you just want them to enter their Account:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', {$portal.google_analytics_account}]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

{literal}
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
{/literal}
--></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
{literal}
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', {/literal}{$portal.google_analytics_account}{literal}]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);


  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
{/literal}
--></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
   // assuming your Smarty object is $smarty
   $smarty->assign('ga_id','UA-xxxxxx-x');
   $smarty->display('ga.tpl');
 ?>
```

ga.tpl (note that there are *two* `literal` blocks, with the `ga_id` in-between):

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
{literal}
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '{/literal}{$ga_id}{literal}']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ?
                 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +
      '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
{/literal}
--></script>
```